# How can I pass a value to a method and not have it get initialized to 0 when it is called?

Tags: java, android, methods, parameter-passing

> When I called this function and pass in values(eg. 2000) the values are not being passed. Instead it is being initialized to 0.

Log: The value of Vehicle Surtax = 0.0

```
public void Category19(final double x){
    Log.d(TAG, "The value of VehSurtaxTotal = " + x);
}
```

> Here is Where the function is being called

```
public void CustomDuties() {  // Calculates the duties on each Item

    acTV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
            int pos = -1;

            // Finds the item that was selected in the Array and returns it's position
            for (int i = 0; i < ItemList.length; i++) {
                if (ItemList[i].equals(selection)) {
                    pos = i;
                    break;
                }
            }

            switch (pos) {
                case 314:
                    Category19(0.00);
                    break;
                case 315:
                    Category19(0.00);
                    break;
                case 316:
                    Category19(0.00);
                    break;
                case 317:
                    Category19(0.00);
                    break;
                case 324:
                    Category19(1269.78);
                    break;
                case 325:
                    Category19(1472.21);
                    break;
                case 326:
                    Category19(1693.04);
                    break;
                case 327:
                    Category19(2024.29);
                    break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please print/tell selected position, that will help.

Comment: Are you sure the program is calling your function with a value different than `0`? As Rasi suggested, telling us the value of the variable `pos` would be helpful.

Comment: Also, name the parameter something more descriptive, not x. If it is VehSurtaxTotal  then name it that vehSurtaxTotal

Comment: pos is the value of what ever is selected in the autocompletetextview drop down. It gets the value of that selected item from the arraylist and stores in in pos. @AlLelopath I'll change it back

Comment: @BurnedCreationz yes but what is the value of `pos` when you get `0.0`? you should log `pos` before the switch statement.

Comment: In addition of @AlLelopath suggestion, I would change the name of the method `Category19`. Method names should be verbs with no numbers on it.

Comment: The position is 317 shows 317 in the log when selected @tima .

Comment: Thanks for the tip @LucasColombo I'll change them

Comment: @BurnedCreationz that case passes `0.0` which is what you are seeing in the log, which is correct

Comment: I see the problem, the for loop is not doing it's job in selecting the the item which was clicked on in the order it is in the arrayAdapter. It is setting the position randomly. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: I figured it out. Thanks for your help guys